# not able to prevent start of video

Tags: ios, video

hi im viewing  an array of video in tableview using the url from my server im getting some issues with the video play. im not able to pause the videos only first video is getting pauses all remaining video are playing automatically.

how to pasuse all the videos ?

this is the code i have used

```
 self.titile.text = inVideosObj.title;
url =[NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"UDSA %@  %@ ",url,request);


connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
MPMoviePlayerController *mov = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:  [NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video]];
NSLog(@"length %d",[self.responseData length]);


self.movieplayer = mov;
[self.movieplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20, 100, 100)];

// self.movieplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.movieplayer.view];
    [self.movieplayer prepareToPlay];
[self.movieplayer pause];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try disabling autoplay:

```
 self.movieplayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
```

The setting defaults to `YES`